# Using {...state} to create new instance of object with only one filed modified is not working in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a simple React JS application. I'm using Redux.

I'm trying to modify the state of a reducer and create a new instance of it and return. But it is throwing an error.

Here is my reducer code:

```
export default function reducer(state={
    tweets : [ "How are you doing" ],
    name : ""
}, action){
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_TWEETS': {
            return {...state, tweets: ["How", "are", "you", "doing"]};
        }
    }
    return {...state};
}
```

As you can see this line:

```
return {...state, tweets: ["How", "are", "you", "doing"]},
```

I'm trying to change the value of tweets field and create a new instance of the object with other fields remain the same.

But, when I run my project, it is giving me the sort of syntax error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/reducers/tweetsReducer.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/RealProject/src/app/reducers/tweetsReducer.js: Unexpected token (8:20)

   6 |     {
   7 |         case 'FETCH_TWEETS': {
>  8 |             return {...state, tweets: ["How", "are", "you", "doing"]};
     |                     ^
   9 |         }
  10 |     }
  11 |     return {...state};
```

So, what is wrong with my code? Is there any other way around to modify only one field of the object and create new instance?

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "realproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234 --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "flux": "^3.1.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

This is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: [ 'transform-decorators-legacy' ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Which babel-presets do you have configured? Maybe you're missing one (like e.g. "env") that allows for ES6...

Comment: Possibly an issue with your babel compiler; have you been about to use the spread operator successfully elsewhere?

Comment: @SebastianRothbucher I have updated the question to show you the package.json and the webpack.config files. What is missing? I am a bit struggling coz I am new to the React world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the problem likely lies with the transpiling of the spread syntax. You can also accomplish this without that syntax using `Object.assign`

```
switch(action.type) {
  case 'FETCH_TWEETS':
    return Object.assign(
      {}, state, { tweets: ["How", "are", "you", "doing"] }
    );
  default:
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the [transform-object-rest-spread babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/) for Object Rest/Spread Properties which is at stage 4.